How to configure TLSConfiguration in python-mbedtls to use NULL ciphers suites in handshake
I'm working on a python project which I'm establishing (D)TLS communication with industrial devices using python-mbedtls. To implement integrity only communication profile, I need to use NULL cipher suites like TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA and TLS-ECDHE-PSK-WITH-NULL-SHA256.
I don't know how to configure the mbedTLS context to allow me using of those cipher suites. Does py mbedTLS support weak ciphers at all?
